# Error con ruta POST en api Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, axios

**MI RUTA**

```
Route::post('/send_foto/', 'GestionController@foto');
```

**MI CONSULTA**

```
var data ="fafa";
axios.post('api/send_foto/',data)
                    .then(response => {
})
```

[image: ERROR CON METODO POST]

[image: RESPUESTA EN CONSOLA]

**RESPUESTA EN CONSOLA**

Comment: ¿Eso es lo que te devuelve como respuesta axios? por que si accedes a la ruta en el navegador es claro que te va a dar error de Método por que el navegador accede por GET, lo que tienes que revisar es la respuesta en la consola del navegador.

Comment: Pero al verlo en el navegador estas haciendo una petición `GET` y tu controlador esta esperando un `POST`, por eso la excepcion `MethodNotAllowed`. ademas en axios estas llamando a `api/send_foto/` y tu ruta es `/send_foto/`, a menos que tengas un grupo sobre la ruta se podria explicar.

Comment: tiene como prefijo api, porque la ruta esta en el archivo api de las rutas de laravel

Comment: Ok pero muestra el resultado que te aparece cuando haces la peticion AJAX en consola. No lo que te aparece en el navegador.

Comment: ya subi una imagen donde se puede apreciar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente sea por un [error `301`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). Prueba modificar tu ruta quitando el `/` final:

```php
Route::post('/send_foto', 'GestionController@foto');
```

Luego en Axios:

```js
var data ="data";
axios.post('api/send_foto',data)
         .then(response => {
            //
})
```

PD: Esto asumiendo que ya has configurado la ruta base en axios (para añadir `<url_base>/`)

---

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208440/axios-xmlhttprequest-is-sending-get-instead-of-post-in-production-environment) puedes conseguir más info.